# Creating a root user MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, server, database

I currently have a server running mongodb that has a number of users. 
Currently there is a root user that has the following roles: 
ClusterAdmin
userAdminAnyDatabase
readAnyDatabase

The problem is that I want to create a new datbase. Now I have been able to do this but i cannot add any collections to it as I do not have the correct roles assigned to the root account I am using.

Now I have tried to create a new user eg 'superuser' that will be able to do this. But I do not have the permissions to do this. Is there a way that I cant get around this in order to make a new user?

Any help in regards to this problem would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a user in your database, the [localhost exception](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#localhost-exception) won't work so you will need to  start mongod using the [noauth](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/configuration-options/#noauth) option OR [auth](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/configuration-options/#auth) option.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#first-user-restrictions